# Phalcon 2 vs Phalcon 3 instantiate model

Tags: php, phalcon, autoloader

I've migrated my Phalcon project from 2 to 3 and get some unexpected behavior. In my loader I do this:

```
<?php
use Phalcon\Loader;

$loader = new Loader();

$loader->registerDirs(
    array(
        $config->application->libraryDir,
        $config->application->controllersDir,
        $config->application->modelsDir
    )
);

$loader->register();
```

Now, when I try to instantiate one of my models in my controller-action the code halts:

```
$present = new \Present();
```

Results in a "recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream" error in /var/log/nginx/error.log.

However, when I instantiate the class directly in my loader.php file the model is auto-loaded and I can instantiate it anywhere. The workaround for the controller action is:

```
if (class_exists('Present')) { // THIS triggers the autoloader
    $present = new \Present();
    $present->save();
}
```

So the issue is solved for now. My question is: why doesn't

```
new \Present()
```

trigger the auto-loader in the controller-action as I expected? Why did it work under Phalcon 2? Why does it work when I do it directly in the loader.php or in public/index.php?

Comment: Have you read this issue? https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/2642. It links to another issue that suggests to re-compile Phalcon manually. How did you install Phalcon 3 btw?

Comment: @Timothy: I followed the steps on https://phalconphp.com/en/download ...
curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/phalcon/stable/script.deb.sh | sudo bash and then
sudo apt-get install php7.0-phalcon. Perhaps recompiling works. Are there other issues with the packaged version?

Comment: @Timothy: I guess my issue differs from the one you are referring to. I did have an issue with save but that had to do with the double creation of $di = new FactoryDefault();